# python flask how to access CLI from terminal when running application from Pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, command-line-interface, backend

I am using python 2.7 with flask and using pycharm professional IDE, I am running the flask application using a virtual environment from inside pycharm.

When I open a terminal inside pycharm and use CLI commands, it works, and when I open a terminal (regular terminal) outside of the IDE, and trying to use the same command it's not working, the app is still running all the time, and the command is excactly the same.

When I try to activate the same venv outside of the IDE i get permission issue, I assume that it has to do with the venv already being active inside the IDE.

What is the issue? I need to run the same virtual environment in order to use the CLI commands?

How can i access the CLI commands from outside of the IDE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to activate the same venv outside of the IDE I get permission issue

Most likely the problem is all about permission access to the virtual environment's files. Check out access permissions and `user:group` ownership using `ls -al` (if you're on Mac or Linux), more info here:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls

https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

> I assume that it has to do with the venv already being active inside the IDE

Definitely not, you can activate it as many times as you want.

> I need to run the same virtual environment in order to use the CLI commands?

At least you have to have all the dependencies installed in your other environment (global or virtual) if you have plans to use one.

> when I open a terminal (regular terminal) outside of the IDE, and trying to use the same command it's not working

You'd better post a full error output so that we could check the actual error. Also what command are you trying to run?

Comment: Why do i need the dependencies installed, in order to approach a running app via a CLI? doesn't it work the same as a restful API would? approach via a port?

Comment: You could start with posting the commands you're trying to run and also the full error message. Honestly it's not that simple to help someone being blindfolded ;) That would be cool if you will update your question.